# C++ : extern variable inside namespace and printf vs cout

Tags: c++, namespaces, printf, extern, cout

i have a little problem with printf and i don't know why !

=>kernel.h

```
#ifndef KERNEL_H
#define KERNEL_H

namespace kernel
{
    extern const double h;
}

#endif // KERNEL_H
```

=>kernel.cpp

```
#include <kernel.h>

namespace kernel
{
    const double kernel::h=85.0;
}
```

=>main.cpp

```
#include "kernel.h"
#include <iostream>
//#include <cstdio>//With cstdio, it is the same problem !

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    using namespace kernel;

    double a = h;

    printf("printf a is %d\n",a);
    std::cout<<"std::cout a is " << a << std::endl;

    printf("printf h is %d\n",h);
    printf("printf kernel::h is %d\n",kernel::h);
    std::cout << "std::cout h is " << h << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And my output on my console is :

```
printf a is 0
std::cout a is 85
printf h is 0
printf kernel::h is 0
std::cout h is 85
```

Why printf doesn't work? Because it is a C function ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it really necessary to include kernel.h in kernel.cpp?

Comment: It is not an error, but the definition in the cpp file is excessive. You could do either `const double kernel::h=85.0` (without reopening the namespace), or just `const double h=85.0` if you reopened it. You kinda "did both", which is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is because you are printing it as an `integer`.
Try `%lg` or `%lf`

```
printf("printf kernel::h is %lg\n",kernel::h);
```

If you turn on **warnings** the compiler would have told you the problem. `-Wformat`

or just use `std::cout` and you won't have this kind of problems

```
std::cout << kernel::h;
```

Answer (score 2):

`%d` is for integers, you are trying to print a `double` as an `int`. I think you'd want `%lf` for `long float` for doubles? Never actually printf'd a double before.

Comment: ok my bad ! I'm really stupid ! It's work correctly with %f , you are right %d, it's only for int... Thanks a lot